# How to develop a spring XD custom job to download a file from SFTP location and save it on local machine

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-xd

I'm trying to develop a custom job to download a file from SFTP location using spring XD. It'll really help if you could give me some guidance on this as I'm pretty much new on this.

Comment: There is already an FTP/SFTP source for doing this out of the box.  Is there something beyond that you're looking for?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: yeah there is a default job to download a file from the FTP and save it on hdfs. I just need to save it on my Spring XD running machine instead saving it on hdfs. Do you have any thought on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [FTP source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#ftp) on the stream side of XD.

If you want to do it with a job you can create a simple job that uses an `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` or an `FtpOutboundGateway` (both from spring-integration-ftp) to fetch the file.